# Unable to connect aws document db from node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Here is my node.js code using to connect document db. I have ssl file also there. I am able to connect from mongoshell but not working from node.js app

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
//db connection
const dbConnect = require("./dbConnection.js");
const globalErrorMiddleware = require("./middlewares/appErrorHandler");

mongoose.connect(
"mongodb://lbw:dkdDKsKsl@dev-docdb-cluster-1.cluster-ct090j7ac20n.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/cnox?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false",
process.env.ENV === "LIVE"
    ? {
        ssl: true,
        sslValidate: true,
        sslCA: `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`,
    }
    : {}
);
```

I am getting below error when connecting to db . Please take a look

```
app listening on port: 5600
/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:203
                    callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
                            ^

MongoServerError: Authorization failure
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:203:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at processIncomingData (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:777:22) {
ok: 0,
operationTime: Timestamp { low: 1, high: 1652288522, unsigned: true },
code: 13,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running to a very similar problem with using the mongodb javascript client.  The mongo shell is much more forgiving to the server configuration than the some of the other clients.

There a couple of things you can try:

1. add `directConnection=true` to your connection string.
2. add `authSource=cnox`
3. try those separately and in combination.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/#direct-connection

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/authenticating/

Another guess is that you are successfully connecting but then the code is trying to something that isn't authorized.  Like trying to interact with another database other than `cnox` or running a command that isn't supported by the current user rights.